# Should I upgrade my mbp internal hard drive (160 gb) with a 64 gb SSD?

Tags: ssd

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Does the use of SSD give one a dramatic performance boost?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7345/does-the-use-of-ssd-give-one-a-dramatic-performance-boost)
>   [Replace MacBook Pro hard disk with SSD](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/replace-macbook-pro-hard-disk-with-ssd)

Should I upgrade my mbp internal hard drive (160 gb) with a 64 gb SSD? How much improvement will I see?

Comment: Duplicate: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/7345/does-the-use-of-ssd-give-one-a-dramatic-performance-boost

Answer (score 2):

If you only use 40-50 gb on your disk, sure. The performance improvement will be very noticeable.