# What's the best after-market SSD for my MBP?

Tags: upgrade, ssd

I've been researching various SSD's to put in my 2011 MBP, and I've come across quite a few reviews and threads indicating various reliability and performance issues, even with the popular models.

For example, I've read that the OCZ Vertex 3 models are very popular, but I've also read that they have intractable issues.

Can someone give me some advice or experiences they've had with various brands? Is OCZ Vertex 3 a good choice or does it have issues with MBPs?

PS: I know that what is "best" may be subjective, and I know that this is similar to [this older post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3772/what-are-some-tips-for-replacing-my-macbook-pro-hard-disk-with-ssd), but I still think it would be valuable to have an up-to-date version of this question as HW options change frequently.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different! Shopping recommendations are off-topic for this site. Please see the [FAQs](http://apple.stackexchange.com/faq) for more details. Thakns!

Answer (score 1):

The best available data are not yet good enough to separate fact from fiction on SSD reliability among vendors or even as compared to spinning metal.

There's [an excellent review at Tom's Hardware](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/ssd-reliability-failure-rate,2923.html) that explores what is currently known about SSD reliability.

From the article:

> ... Many of the IT managers we interviewed reiterated that Intel's SLC-based SSDs are the shining standard by which others are measured. But ... there's nothing to suggest that its products are significantly more reliable than the best hard drive solutions. We don’t have failure rates beyond two years of use for SSDs, so it’s possible that this story will change.

Answer (score 0):

It's always worth revisiting this great [post](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2010/09/revisiting-solid-state-hard-drives.html) by Jeff Atwood on the subject. It includes benchmarks. Hope this helps.